# Can the anonymous functions declared inside of Array.forEach() cannot return values in JavaScript? See code below for getting a better picture

Tags: javascript, foreach, array.prototype.map

I am a newbie in Development World , Please help me getting rid of this little doubt !
In the arrayName.map(anonymous Function 1) and arrayName.forEach(anonymous Function 2) , The anonymous Function 1 returns values but the anonymous Function 2 is not able to return values. See
The code below for example !

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

var numbers = [3, 56, 2, 48, 5];
console.log(numbers.map(function(number){
  return number*number
}))

console.log(numbers.forEach(function(number){
  return number*number
}))
```

Here in above code , The .map() returns value and we can see output in log , But unlike in .forEach() the only output we get is "undefined".We can achieve the above using below method

```
const numberSquare=[];
numbers.forEach(function(number){
  numberSquare.push(number*number)
})
console.log(numberSquare);
```

**So is it that Anonymous Function declared inside of foreach() cannot return values?**

Comment: `forEach` performs an action over each value in the array and ultimately modifying the original array, whist `map` performs an action on each value of the original array while not modifying it, resulting in the map function returning a new collection with the values modified. Basically a `forEach`would do this `value = myFunc(value) ? myFunc(value) : value` whilst the map function would do `newArray.push(myFunc(value))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are new to development, you can take a look at the MDN docs about forEach and map.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

These are totally different functions.

As you can see, forEach returns undefined so that's what you see logged. Map creates a new array with whatever is returned in its callback so that's what you see in the console.
What you return in your example in the anonymous function is not returned by forEach in the outer console.log. Your second example to create the array with squared numbers and forEach is correct. However, for what you want I would always use map since it does exactly what you need.

And if you want just to console.log the squared numbers with forEach you can do like this:

```
numbers.forEach(function(number) { console.log(number * number); });
```

But this will not create the array, will just log them.
Take care!

Answer (score 1):

The forEach function in javascript doesn't return values in general. It's just used as iterator function like a for loop. If you need values, you have to use for example map, filter, find, findIndex or reduce or use it like you did in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

from mdn docs
The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once for each array element.

in general its just a loop over array items

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array1.forEach(element => console.log(element));

// expected output: "a"
// expected output: "b"
// expected output: "c"
```

The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];

// pass a function to map
const map1 = array1.map(x => x * 2);

console.log(map1);
// expected output: Array [2, 8, 18, 32]
```

Answer (score 1):

Totally agreed and thanks to everyone for clearing my doubt !
Also below I got an interesting blog which aims at pointing out the differences between  "forEach()" and "map()" methods . Do give it a read
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/4-main-differences-between-foreach-and-map/